# Date management problem in a trigger with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, trigger

I created two tables on PostgreSQL.

I would like to note in a layer a date and retrieve:
the corresponding year in a variable,
then reuse the year variable in various other attributes integrating attributes from the second table.

To do this, I have a function launched by a trigger.

My problem is linked to the fact that if I note a date 01/01/2020 I do not recover the year 2020 in my variables.
Could anyone tell me where the problem is coming from?
There is a shift, the year is assigned to the 2nd line (see capture).

```
DROP TABLE public.test;
CREATE TABLE public.test
(id_sign SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,   
s_date_signal date, 
code_insee VARCHAR(5),
nom varchar(150),  
annee_signal integer,
cle_1 VARCHAR(150),
cle_2 VARCHAR(150), 
cle_3 VARCHAR (20), 
geom geometry(point,2154));

 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.concat_2_var (s1 varchar, s2 varchar, s3 varchar) RETURNS varchar AS
$body$
BEGIN
RETURN s1||s2||s3;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.t_maj ()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT date_part('year', s_date_signal) from public.test INTO NEW.annee_signal;
SELECT DISTINCT public.concat_2_var(NEW.code_insee::varchar,'-',NEW.id_sign::varchar) from public.t_test_com INTO NEW.cle_1;
SELECT DISTINCT public.concat_2_var(NEW.annee_signal::varchar,'-',NEW.cle_1::varchar) from public.t_test_com INTO NEW.cle_2;
SELECT DISTINCT public.concat_2_var(NEW.annee_signal::varchar,'-',NEW.id_sign::varchar) from public.t_test_com INTO NEW.cle_3;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER t_maj_t 
BEFORE INSERT
ON public.test
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.t_maj  ();
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each inserted row, you are fetching ***the complete list*** of `DISTINCT date_part('year', s_date_signal)` entries ***from the `public.test` table***, of which the ***first record in random (semi-deterministic, or by PK) order*** is chosen for assignment to `NEW.annee_signal`.

I do not quite understand the motive behind fetching data from a table in this and all following statements, but my guess is you want to directly access the `NEW.s_date_signal` record field instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.t_maj()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
  $BODY$
  BEGIN
    NEW.annee_signal := DATE_PART('YEAR', NEW.s_date_signal)::INT;

    NEW.cle_1 := public.concat_2_var(NEW.code_insee::varchar,'-',NEW.id_sign::varchar);
    NEW.cle_2 := public.concat_2_var(NEW.annee_signal::varchar,'-',NEW.cle_1::varchar);
    NEW.cle_3 := public.concat_2_var(NEW.annee_signal::varchar,'-',NEW.id_sign::varchar);
    
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
```

*Note that, with your setup you will also need `TRIGGER` logic in place to handle `UPDATE`s to the columns used in the expressions! My suggestion: take a look at my last point below.*

---

**Bonus:**

- Use `CONCAT_WS` instead of a cumbersome re-implementation of its logic:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.t_maj()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
    $BODY$
    BEGIN
      NEW.annee_signal := DATE_PART('YEAR', NEW.s_date_signal);

      NEW.cle_1 := CONCAT_WS('-', NEW.code_insee, NEW.id_sign)::VARCHAR;
      NEW.cle_2 := CONCAT_WS('-', NEW.annee_signal, NEW.code_insee, NEW.id_sign)::VARCHAR;
      NEW.cle_3 := CONCAT_WS('-', NEW.annee_signal, NEW.id_sign)::VARCHAR;

      RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
  ;
  ```
- Follow normalization rules and avoid data duplication - retrieve the concatenated values explicitly ***when accessing the table***, instead of storing them *in* the table. If `annee_signal` is of no use other than being part of the `cle` expressions, don't store it either. The main benefit other than storage overhead is that `UPDATE`s to the table are immediately projected.

  - Here you can go the syntactic sugar way and write yourself some *composite type functions*, e.g.:

    ```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cle_1(
      IN  public.test,    -- pass the specific table composite type
      OUT VARCHAR
    ) IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
      LANGUAGE SQL AS
      $BODY$
        SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', $1.code_insee, $1.id_sign)::VARCHAR;
      $BODY$
    ;

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cle_2(
      IN  public.test,    -- pass the specific table composite type
      OUT VARCHAR
    ) IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
      LANGUAGE SQL AS
      $BODY$
        SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', DATE_PART('YEAR', $1.s_date_signal), $1.code_insee, $1.id_sign)::VARCHAR;
      $BODY$
    ;

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cle_3(
      IN  public.test,    -- pass the specific table composite type
      OUT VARCHAR
    ) IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
      LANGUAGE SQL AS
      $BODY$
        SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', DATE_PART('YEAR', $1.s_date_signal), $1.id_sign)::VARCHAR;
      $BODY$
    ;
    ```

    which you can then use in a `SELECT` like this:

    ```
    SELECT
      t.id_sign,
      t.cle_1,    -- the functions always have to be fully qualified with the table name or alias - so it cannot be just 'cle_1`, it has to be 't.cle_1'!
      t.cle_2,
      t.cle_3
    FROM
      public.test AS t
    ;
    ```

    Alternatively, use a similar function to get all three concatenated values in one go:

    ```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cl(
      IN  public.test,    -- pass the specific table composite type
      OUT e_1 VARCHAR,
      OUT e_2 VARCHAR,
      OUT e_3 VARCHAR
    ) IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
      LANGUAGE SQL AS
      $BODY$
        SELECT
          CONCAT_WS('-', $1.code_insee, $1.id_sign)::VARCHAR,
          CONCAT_WS('-', annee_signal, $1.code_insee, $1.id_sign)::VARCHAR,
          CONCAT_WS('-', annee_signal, $1.id_sign)::VARCHAR
        FROM
          DATE_PART('YEAR', $1.s_date_signal) AS annee_signal
        ;
      $BODY$
    ;
    ```

    and use it by directly accessing the returned fields, or expanding its results with `*`:

    ```
    SELECT
      t.id_sign,
      t.cl.e_1,
      t.cl.e_2,
      t.cl.e_3
      -- or simply t.cl.*
    FROM
      public.test AS t
    ;
    ```
- Alternatively, **use [`GENERATED` columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html)** - **they are made for this**, and while technically *storing* data they are a superb way to keep the `UPDATE` dependencies intact for purely computationally derived column values, without writing additional `TRIGGER` logic.

  First we need an `IMMUTABLE` version of `CONCAT_WS` in order to work on `GENERATED` columns:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION immutable_concat_ws(
    text,
    VARIADIC text[]
  ) RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE internal
    IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
      'text_concat_ws'
  ;
  ```

  *Note that you need **superuser** privileges to create `LANGUAGE internal` functions - if that is not possible, write a simple `LANGUAGE SQL` wrapper using `CONCAT_WS`.*

  and then we use it in the respective column definitions:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE public.test(
    id_sign       INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, --recommended way to add a serial id   
    s_date_signal DATE, 
    code_insee    VARCHAR(5),
    nom           VARCHAR(150),  
    annee_signal  INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( DATE_PART('YEAR', s_date_signal)::INT ) STORED,
    cle_1         VARCHAR(150) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( IMMUTABLE_CONCAT_WS('-', code_insee, id_sign) ) STORED,
    cle_2         VARCHAR(150) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( IMMUTABLE_CONCAT_WS('-', DATE_PART('YEAR', s_date_signal), code_insee, id_sign) ) STORED, 
    cle_3         VARCHAR (20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( IMMUTABLE_CONCAT_WS('-', DATE_PART('YEAR', s_date_signal), id_sign) ) STORED, 
    geom          GEOMETRY(POINT, 2154)
  );
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very complete, very enriching and very educational. Good day !